# sync changes from azure fileshare back to onprem file server

Tags: azure, azure-storage

we are migrating TBs of files from onprem fileshare to azure file storage and use it as primary share.  I understand Azure file sync can do this job  we want to keep a local backup in a different server on prem.  while file sync replicate changes back to onprem, but from what I understand, the frequency of sync happens every 24 hours from azure to onprem.  Is it possible to increase that frequency? could we leverage databox for initial migration?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

•   Since Azure file share doesn’t have change notifications or journaling like there is on Windows Server, i.e., Windows USN journaling service which automatically detects any changes in the file share sync folder and automatically initiates a sync session with the Azure file share. Due to which, there is no way you can change the scheduled sync job cycle for Azure file sync. But, instead of changing the azure file sync scheduled sync cycle, you can use the following command to immediately sync the files that are changed in Azure file share: -

```
 ‘ Invoke-AzStorageSyncChangeDetection -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" - 
  StorageSyncServiceName "myStorageSyncServiceName" -SyncGroupName 
   "mySyncGroupName" -CloudEndpointName "b38fc242-8100-4807-89d0-399cef5863bf" - 
    DirectoryPath "Examples" -Recursive -AsJob -PassThru ‘
```

This cmdlet is intended for scenarios where some type of automated process is making changes in the Azure file share, or the changes are done by an administrator (like moving files and directories into the share).

•   Yes, you can leverage Azure DataBox in case you have more than 500TB of Data to be transferred to the cloud share and want to set it up and use it immediately or as early as possible on a whole. Also, ensure that the number of files to be synced to azure file share is less than 10 million as then indexing and their availability is a concern and is still in preview.

Please find the below documentation links for reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq#azure-file-sync

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databox/data-box-faq#when-should-i-use-data-box-